# How does the Mandalorian eat?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In chapter/episode 3 of *The Mandalorian* before his new armor is built, it is said that the Mandalorian never removes his helmet. In this case, how does the Mandalorian eat?

Comment: Blue milkshakes with a straw?

Comment: Man, if he never brushes his teeth he must have _really_ bad breath.  I think the only way that makes sense is with an unstated "in front of other people."

Comment: I had wondered if that mean publicly. Though, they seem to congregate in their hovel with all their masks on. Maybe they have some kind of intravenous nutrient system in their armor. Afterall, needing to eat could get in the way of an efficient bounty hunter

Comment: It could very well be something like a gunfighter who's said never to be unarmed. You know there's times they literally are not wearing a gun, but other people don't see them in that situation.

Comment: Infusions (intravenous or rectal) seem to be an obvious choice. Surprisingly, I couldn't find any confirmation in the canon (old or new).

Comment: @KeithMorrison and DavidW: time for another installment of [*Pedant of the Pedants*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/90943/31394)?

Comment: Is the no removing helmet thing entirely new? Jango removed his. We saw plenty of helmet-less Mandalorians in Rebels.

Comment: He eats very well, thank you.

Comment: The Mandalorian can remove his helmet when he is alone, so he is able to eat, when he is by himself.