# Do Mandalorians truly never remove their helmets?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian, mandalorian

In episode 3 of *The Mandalorian*, it is said that Mandalorians never remove their helmets for any reason. Really? Not even to sleep or bathe? Is there any canonical source for this idea? I’m going to assume that the “never” implies “Never removes their helmets in public…” right?

But in flashback scenes to the Mandalorian’s childhood, nobody is really pictured wearing Mandalorian armor let alone helmets. They simply seemed like basic humans who might just be unified by wearing maroon wardrobes all the time.

So what is the deal with this claim? What is the canonical context of the claim?

[image: “This is the way.”]

---

***Looking for in-universe, canonical explanations; not armchair speculation and theories. If none (currently) exist, legends explanation would suffice. Regardless, please provide references and context.***

Comment: In Clone Wars there was an entire planet of Mandalorians walking around without helmets. In Rebels, there were plenty of Mandalorians wearing helmets and carrying them or leaving them on a table to eat.

Comment: I think there's a strong implication that the protagonist wasn't born a mandalorian - his donations of beskar to foundlings for example. He saved the young yodling because he empathised with the little runt.

Comment: IMHO, duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223468/how-does-the-mandalorian-eat

Comment: I haven't been watching *The Mandalorians*, but I remember that in *Rebels* Sabine Wren took off her helmet pretty much whenever she was aboard their home ship or otherwise in a relaxed situation. If we take this "never remove their helmets" thing at face value, would that prove that Sabine was a shameless exhibitionist? By the standards of other Mandalorians, it was practically as if she were walking around in the nude all the time with no sense of 'decency'? (Not that I seriously believe this, you understand.)

Comment: Maybe it's only certain tribes

Comment: I don't follow Clone Wars but wasn't there an arc about a pacifist movement that came to power on Mandalore? Perhaps this is an "over-expression" of traditional values, which wouldn't be uncommon when those values were recently questioned or suppressed.

Comment: Pretty much all that. It might not be mandalore though - he might be adopted into the clan and a foundling himself

Comment: agree w/ the foundling statement - seems clear so far that he wasn't born Mando but was found and has joined up. Seems more like a religion than a race just looking at this series

Comment: I don't think it's possible to live your entire adult life wearing a helmet, your skin would get pretty nasty & there'd be open sores from chafing.

Comment: Jango and Boba had no problems removing not wearing helmets in the prequels.

Comment: @Harabeck, thing is Jango and Boba were not Mandalorians. They simply wore the armor. Boba even less so because he was just a clone. Also for NKCampbell, It's not that it's just a religion, the planet's name is Mandalore. So people from there are Mandalorians. Simple as that.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek My understanding of "foundling", especially with the flashback war footage, was that they were orphans from within the community, rather than from the galaxy at large.  The obligation of donating for foundlings was to help those who lost their family to be able to get armor.  I could very well be incorrect in my assumptions.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Although no longer Canon, in Legends the Mandalorian culture is *founded* on adopting the orphaned and outcast - there is basically no difference between a "born" and "adopted" Mandalorian.  This goes back to when the people who would eventually become the first Mandalorians were forced off their home planet by war.  Their own name for themselves - "Mando-ade" - means "Children of Mandalore", which is the title of their leader. This included defeated enemies joining them - much like the old Roman practice of assimilating cultures.  The original Mandalorians were also not human.

Comment: At this point, I almost think whether the Mandalrian Protagonist was a foundling feels like a question of its own

Comment: This reminds of that Clint Eastwood movie, set in the 80s I believe, where he says he only takes off his hat for 2 things.  One of which his lady companion, who had asked, apparently qualifies for.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The direct answer is **Yes** they do remove their helmets per previous visualizations of Mandalorians. Although in *The Mandalorian* they haven't doffed their helmets, nor fully explained why just yet.

It has been proven in previous shows, and even in *The Mandalorian* that they used to walk around without helmets on, or even armor for the most part.

In *Star Wars Rebels* (2014-2018), Sabine Wren is mostly seen without her helmet on, as are most of the Mandalorians in the show.

In *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* (2008) there are episodes involving the Siege of Mandalore. Although in this instance most of the Mandalorians are wearing their armor and helmets, there is a scene where Anakin is shown talking to a Mandalorian female without her helmet on. There are other scenes throughout the pretty long series depicting Manadlorians without their helmets on.

It is also assumed that Mandalorians at some point *have* to doff their armor and helmet in order to eat, bathe, etc. I think it is a general understanding that they only do that in the privacy of their homes and with people they trust their lives with.

Also due to the flashbacks of Din Djarin, you can conclude that wearing the armor at all times was not a custom before. I imagine we will get more information on this throughout the season.

Update: As you have probably seen in the latest episode, they DO in fact remove their helmets. Although we did not see the protagonists face, his helmet was off.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103107/discussion-on-answer-by-j-wagner-do-mandalorians-truly-never-remove-their-helme).

Answer (score 34):

In episode 4, we see him take his helmet off to eat. This is after a villager asks him about removing it. It also clarifies that they do remove their helmets when nobody else is around.

> OMERA: When did you last take that helmet off?
>
> MANDALORIAN: Yesterday
>
> OMERA: I mean in front of other people

Episode 8 furthers this when

> IG11 removes the helmet to tend to Mando's injuries. Mando protests that no living thing has seen him without it since he took the oath, to which IG11 reminds him IG11 not alive.

Answer (score 23):

Apparently Deathwatch/Children of the Watch Mandalorians follow the creed of always wearing the helmet all the time- this is referenced to in the third episode of season 2 "Chapter 11: The Heiress" where Bo-Katan Kryze, and two other mandalorians remove their helmets, much to Din Djarin's shock. Its mentioned that the Watch are religious zealots. Later on, its hinted that they follow a very traditionalist aspect of things. They do seem to be accepting later on of the other, less traditionalist mandalorians, so this is very much a tradition of that group of mandalorians, rather than a universal one. From what the Armorer says - it feels like its a reaction to the fall of mandalore and mandalorian culture.

The Deathwatch apparently ended up being destroyed due to inflighting "Death Watch exists no longer. It shattered into many warring factions" - and I suspect this is very much a reaction to that.

So *some* mandalorians, who follow the specific creed adopted by the Children of the watch do not remove their helmets. As per other media, other factions of Mandalorians, including pre-purge deathwatch *may* not. The 'unified' force that took Mandalore seems to follow whichever tradition their original faction did, whether it be the mandalorians who had survived onworld, Bo Katan's nightowls or the children of the watch

Least in the strict interpretation of the creed that the children of the watch Din follows, removal of the helmet's considered disgraceful, and requires him to redeem himself.

Interestingly - Bo Katan's *told* to remove her helmet by the armorer - and she's told "You walk two worlds" - and there's no disgrace there.

Since she never removes her helmet in the covert - this very much seems a tradition *only* of the night watch.

---

I think there’s a certain amount of context. Or as Obi Wan would say: “From a certain point of view.”

The [Paz Vizsla](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Paz_Vizla) (aka: [Heavy Infantry Mandalorian](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Heavy_Infantry_Mandalorian)) is questioning the protagonist’s (Din Djarin) courage:

> “Our world was shattered by the Empire with whom this coward shares tables.”

Then he tries to remove the protagonist’s *helmet*, which triggers the fight. Disrespect was meant and given out by that action. The helmet is clearly important and removal of it was meant to be symbolic.

> “When one chooses to walk the way of the Mandalore, you are both hunter and prey.”

There’s a certain reputation to that armour, and considering the Empire apparently has them in hiding, even after they are gone, there’s obviously a certain risk to being seen as a Mandalorian.

> “How can one be a coward if one chooses this way of life?”

Kinda backs it up. There’s a risk to being seen as a Mandalorian.

> “Have you ever removed your helmet?”

In previous context — is almost like saying, “Have you ever denied being a Mandalorian?”

Considering Paz’s distaste for hiding this makes sense:

> “Has it ever been removed by others?”

Would presumably suggest defeat.

I suspect this doesn’t mean they live in their helmets — and considering the response “This is the way…” and how that immediately stopped the fight — I suspect there was some cultural and religious implications there.

I’m also pretty sure the protagonist will lose his helmet at some point…

While I’ve yet to watch the episode in question, this recap on [io9](https://io9.gizmodo.com/the-mandalorian-cant-catch-a-break-1840074152) seems to confirm that the protagonist does remove his helmet to eat:

> “Mando hasn’t taken off his helmet in front of people since he was a kid, but (as many people wondered after the comments last week) he does take it off to eat if he’s alone.”

---

Din Djarin *does* remove his helmet later on - in the episode Chapter 15: The Believer, when infiltrating an imperial remnant base. It obviously causes him pain and discomfort. He also removes it in the season finale (By choice, and much more happily). This causes him to be rejected by the Tribe/Covert, and he's told he needs to find the living waters of mandalore

---

When Bo Katan's temporarily taken the creed, and she's on a hunting party to retrieve a foundling carried away by a very large bird-like creature, they camp for the night, and has to ask "How do you eat when other people are around" - and is told they just wander off and do so.

So, from a certain point of view, you don't remove your helmet in the *presence* of other  people.

Comment: As an aside - I typed in the quotes while watching the relevant sections of the episode. Feel free to make corrections to my spelling. Also calling the Main Mandalorian the protagonist seems chunky. I like "Heavy" and 'Armourer' for the other two mandalorians with lines... but for the hero... I donno.

Comment: Quick note to future readers - the information for this is spread out so far across 2 (or 1/2 series) and multiple episodes of a ongoing series. There's probably gonna be more (spoilery!) updates soon. As such apologies for the edits and slightly messy layout of the answer.

Answer (score 13):

I’ve already accepted [an answer that does a nice job of summarizing Mandalorian mythos and customs](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/223517/14850) throughout the series, but episode 4 of *The Mandalorian* (“Sanctuary”) explains it very well in one simple scene:

After coming to a local village on the planet [Sorgan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sorgan), he meets the villagers — including [Omera](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Omera) — who asks the same obvious question about the helmet and this exchange occurs:

> **Omera**: “Do you mind if I ask you something?”
>
> **Din Djarin**: “Go ahead.”
>
> **Omera**: “How long has it been since you’ve taken that off?”
>
> **Din Djarin**: “Yesterday.”
>
> **Omera**: “I mean in front of someone else?”
>
> **Din Djarinn**: (While looking at the children playing outside.) “I wasn’t much older than they are.”
>
> **Omera**: “You haven’t shown your face to anyone since you were a kid?”
>
> **Din Djarin** “No. I was happy that they took me in. My parents were killed and the Mandalorians took care of me.”
> **Omera**: “I’m sorry.”
>
> **Din Djarin** “This is the way.”
>
> **Omera**: “Let us know if there’s anything you need.”
>
> **Din Djarin**: “Thank you.”

She the leaves and we see Din Djarin sitting down at a table near a window with a plate of food; he has taken his helmet off and is watching the children play outside.

[image: Din Djarin sitting down to eat a meal and watch the children play with his helmet off.]

And to further clarify things, episode 8 of *The Mandalorian* (“ Redemption”) further explains the helmet thing in this scene with IG-11; no “living thing” can see a Mandalorian without their helmet on:

> **IG-11**: “I need to remove your helmet if I am to save you.”
>
> **Din Djarin** “Try it and I'll kill you. It is forbidden. No living thing has seen me without my helmet since I swore the Creed.”
>
> **IG-11**: “I am not a living thing.”

And with that, Din Djarin removes his helmet so IG-11 can treat his wounds:

[image: A wounded Din Djarin with his helmet removed so IG-11 — a non living thing — can treat his wounds.]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know everything about the Mandalorians, but I can tell you that in the *KOTOR 1* video game, you can meet and bring in your team one Mandalorian leader that is [Canderous Ordo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Canderous_Ordo). He is not all the time in full armor.  He is an interesting addition in the game.

But those stories happen a long time ago before the SW movies so maybe since the tradition of never removing their helmet happened.

Also, *The Old Republic* stories, despite having a good success (KOTOR 1 & 2 video game + Star Wars MMORPG "The Old Republic") don't seem to be "canon" (means not recognized officially by Disney who owns the licence nowadays). But I don't see how we can ignore so many years of published *Star Wars* content that made many *Star Wars* fans delight ! So I presume you can count on this helmess Mandalorian!

Comment: By the way I found that my answer is very accurate since Disney is considering to bring back the Old Republic part in the official canon, one movie on the topic is already finished to write, or not far. See here : https://www.buzzfeednews.com/article/kateaurthur/new-star-wars-movie-knights-of-the-old-republic

Comment: Regardless of whether Disney are *thinking* about bringing KotOR back into canon, it currently **isn't** part of Canon.  You are also basing your answer on the one Mandalorian we see without helmet  - nor Mandalorian armour, either - in the games, who has major doubts about the Mandalorian leadership and has, effectively, "left".  Spoilers, but his character arc is all about accepting that the Mandalorian people *haven't* lost their way and can be redeemed.  The rest of the KotOR Mandalorians are all wearing both helmet and armour.

Comment: Yes Chronocidal you are right but from my knowledge it's the only time that we see Mandalorians like this so I thought that it worthed at least to mention it. I always wondered if they were like humans or some kind of weird aliens under the armor. Since Disney gave an official work of preparation of movies around these stories, we might see all of that soon. But for the moment we have to keep it on the side.

Comment: And by the way he is definitely a real Mandalorian :

we see him in full armor and helmet : Ordo as Mandalore the Preserver. https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/starwars/images/b/bb/CanderousOrdoOnTheRavager.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20071206234925

You can learn about his legendary fate here : https://swgames.fandom.com/wiki/Mandalore_the_Preserver

Comment: So, we see him in armour only **after** finishing the storyline in which he decides that the Mandalorians *might* be redeemable, and he should return to them instead of abandoning his people?  Not exactly strengthening your point there...

Comment: I'm not aiming about proving something or trying to force people to agree to what I say ^^ I'm just talking about a topic I really like and showing what is an important part of the possible written storylines.

Comment: As per the [tour], StackExchange is not a forum.  Ask questions, receive answers - *"just talking about a topic I really like and showing what is an important part of the possible written storylines."* is, unfortunately, outside of the scope of this website.

Comment: I'm happy to confirm that my answer was perfectly accurate and in line with what already exists. Sabine Wren is an helmess Mandalorian in Star Wars Rebel, and in The Mandalorian serial, we recently got confirmation that only those who are following a specific Mandalorian code always keep their helmet.

Comment: Also, Canderous Ordo became Mandalore the Preserver, it's obvious that if he is the number one Mandalorian, he is the example for his people. 
He was depicted in Star Wars Tales comics, which are canon. So he is canon.
I was fully right and @Chronocidal was totally wrong. Too bad this guy was just trying to prove his point, it doesn't help to bring accurate answers here.

Comment: "Star Wars Tales" were published between 1999 and 2005. In April 2014, pretty much everything except the 6 films and The Clone Wars TV show was declared non-Canon (And, even **before** that, "Star Wars Tales" were officially part of "Infinities" - i.e. "non-canon with elements of continuity")  While Mandalore the Great has been confirmed Canon, Mandalore the Preserver has not.